# How to get an objects string and add this to a string array

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of my own class `Case`. The class case provides the method `getCaseNumber()` I want to add all of the cases casenumber to a `String[] caseNumber`. I've tried this

```
public String[] getCaseNumberToTempList(ArrayList<Case> caseList) {

    String[] objectCaseNumber = null; 

    for(int i = 0; i < caseList.size(); i++) {
        objectCaseNumber[i] = caseList.get(i).getCaseNumber();  
    }

    return objectCaseNumber;

}
```

But my compiler complaints about that the `objectCaseNumber` is null at the point insid the for-loop. How can I manage to complete this?

Comment: `objectCaseNumber = new String[caseList.size()]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to create an array to start with, and initialize the variable with a reference to the array. (See the [Java tutorial for arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more information.) For example:

```
String[] objectCaseNumber = new String[caseList.size()];
```

Alternatively, build a `List<String>` (e.g. using `ArrayList`) instead. That's more flexible - in this case it's simple as you know the size up front, but in other cases being able to just *add* to a list makes life a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

1. In idiomatic Java, you wouldn't use `ArrayList` as a parameter type. Use `List`.
2. Slightly more overhead, but simpler and more readable code is to accumulate in another `List` and then convert into an arrray:

---

```
public String[] getCaseNumberToTempList(List<Case> caseList) {
  final List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (Case c : caseList) r.add(c.getCaseNumber());
  return r.toArray(new Case[0]);
}
```

In your code it does make sense to insist on `ArrayList` due to performance implications of random access via `get`, but if you use this kind of code (and I suggest making a habit of it), then you can work with any `List` with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I think you may have misunderstood Arrays as a primitive type. Arrays in java are objects and they need to be initialized before you access it.